# Retrieving the information from text boxes to a list view

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

I am working in asp.net and i have three text boxes(First Name, Last Name, Middle Initials). There is a list view which shows the content, based on the information entered into text boxes. I am trying to make only the Last Name text box is required for proceeding the information. I already connected the sql data source to list view with the following code:

```
    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Information" ID="TabPanel">             
     <ContentTemplate> 

         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
             ConnectionString="<%$ Name of the database %>" 
             SelectCommand="SELECT [UserID], [UserSuffix], [UserAddressLine1], [UserAddressLine2], [UserCity], 
             [UserState], [UserZipCode], [UserPhoneNumber], [UserEmail] FROM [AllUsers]
             WHERE (([UserLastName] = @UserLastName) OR ([UserFirstName] = @UserFirstName) 
             OR ([UserMiddleInitial] = @UserMiddleInitial))">
             <SelectParameters>
                 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtUILastName" Name="UserLastName" 
                     PropertyName="Text" />
                 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtUIFirstName" Name="UserFirstName" 
                     PropertyName="Text" />
                 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtUIMI" Name="UserMiddleInitial" 
                     PropertyName="Text" />
             </SelectParameters>
         </asp:SqlDataSource>

      <table id = "USERINF">
          <tr>
           <td width="196px" class="style8">
             <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text="Please enter First Name:"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style6">

            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUIFirstName" runat="server" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>


           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td width="196px" class="style8">
            <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text="Please enter Last Name:"></asp:Label>

           </td>
           <td class="style6">
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtUILastName" runat="server" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox> 

            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
             ControlToValidate = "txtUILastName" ValidationExpression = "[a-zA-Z ]{1,20}"
             ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="UserInf"
             ErrorMessage="First Name must be only a-z,A-Z characters!" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate = "txtUILastName" ErrorMessage="Please enter Last Name!" 
                   ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="UserInf" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td> 
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td width="196px" class="style8">
            <asp:Label ID="lblMI" runat="server" Text="Please enter Middle Initials:"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style6">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUIMI" runat="server" MaxLength="1" Width="30px" style="text-align: center;
                 margin-left:2px"></asp:TextBox> 

           </td> 
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td width="196px" class="style8">
           </td>
           <td class="style6">
            <asp:Button ID="btnIFind" runat="server" Text="Find" ValidationGroup = "UserInf"/>
```

When i enter only Last Name, it does not retrieve any data from the data source, but it works only if i fill into all text boxes. How can i make only one text box is required for retrieving the information ?

Find button and text boxes don't have any code behind

Comment: Can we see the aspx code for the three text boxes?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtUIFirstName" runat="server" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>                                           <asp:TextBox ID="txtUILastName" runat="server" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>                                           <asp:TextBox ID="txtUIMI" runat="server" MaxLength="1" Width="30px" style="text-align: center;margin-left:2px"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Hi user2200425, you can edit your original question and add the text boxes' code; that'll make it easier to read. Now, at what point does the data get refreshed? Is there a button on your page? I don't see any methods attached to the text boxes, so that's why I'm asking. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Melanie. I just edited the code. As i mentioned text boxes and the button don't have any code behind. Let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [conditional where clause](http://connectsql.blogspot.com/2011/05/sql-server-conditional-where-clause.html).The stored procedure I've created will return data when:

1. Only last name is supplied
2. Both first and last name are supplied
3. First name, last name and middle initials are supplied

If you need to satisfy any other conditions just amend the stored procedure. The reason I've created a stored proc is because the query is substantially bigger now then the one you've started with:

**Firstly create this stored procedure in SQL:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchUsers]
    @UserLastName VARCHAR(MAX),
    @UserFirstName VARCHAR(MAX) = 'NOVALUE',
    @UserMiddleInitial VARCHAR(MAX) = 'NOVALUE'
AS
BEGIN

SELECT [UserID], [UserSuffix], [UserAddressLine1], [UserAddressLine2], [UserCity], 
[UserState], [UserZipCode], [UserPhoneNumber], 
[UserEmail] FROM [AllUsers] 
WHERE 1 = (CASE 

WHEN @UserFirstName <> 'NOVALUE' AND
@UserMiddleInitial <> 'NOVALUE' AND
UserFirstName = @UserFirstName AND
UserLastName = @UserLastName AND
UserMiddleInitial = @UserMiddleInitial THEN 1

WHEN @UserFirstName <> 'NOVALUE' AND
@UserMiddleInitial = 'NOVALUE' AND
UserFirstName = @UserFirstName AND
UserLastName = @UserLastName THEN 1

WHEN @UserFirstName = 'NOVALUE' AND
@UserMiddleInitial = 'NOVALUE' AND
UserLastName = @UserLastName THEN 1
ELSE 0 END)

END
```

**ASPX:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WildLife_EducationConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SearchUsers" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtUILastName" Name="UserLastName" PropertyName="Text"
            Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtUIFirstName" DefaultValue="NOVALUE" Name="UserFirstName" PropertyName="Text"
            Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtUIMI" DefaultValue="NOVALUE" Name="UserMiddleInitial" PropertyName="Text"
            Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<table id="USERINF">
    <tr>
        <td width="196px" class="style8">
            <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text="Please enter First Name:"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td class="style6">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUIFirstName" runat="server" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="196px" class="style8">
            <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text="Please enter Last Name:"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td class="style6">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUILastName" runat="server" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUILastName"
                ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z ]{1,20}" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="UserInf"
                ErrorMessage="First Name must be only a-z,A-Z characters!" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUILastName"
                ErrorMessage="Please enter Last Name!" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="UserInf"
                Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="196px" class="style8">
            <asp:Label ID="lblMI" runat="server" Text="Please enter Middle Initials:"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td class="style6">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUIMI" runat="server" MaxLength="1" Width="30px" Style="text-align: center;
                margin-left: 2px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="196px" class="style8">
        </td>
        <td class="style6">
            <asp:Button ID="btnIFind" runat="server" Text="Find" ValidationGroup="UserInf" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<asp:ListView ID="listView" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="UserCityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserCity") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="UserEmailLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserEmail") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
</form>
```

Comment: That is what i have already tried, it works but it displays me every body with the same middle initial, first and last names. I am trying to display, for example if i fill out all three text boxes and there is only one person who matches middle, first and last names all together in the database.

Comment: Also i tried (([UserLastName] = @UserLastName) AND ([UserFirstName] = @UserFirstName) AND ([UserMiddleInitial] = @UserMiddleInitial))">

Comment: Insted of (([UserLastName] = @UserLastName) OR ([UserFirstName] = @UserFirstName) OR ([UserMiddleInitial] = @UserMiddleInitial))"> but i still have to fill out all three text boxes to retrieve the information